# Laravel 5 response isn't right

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle

I've built a small Laravel project to get data from an open API and return it with the right CORS headers and such. So I'm doing this:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->get('https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/' . $call);
return response()->json(json_decode($res->getBody()))->withHeaders($res->getHeaders());
```

When I make an example call, it returns a weird response, starting with `<?php` followed by the actual JSON response. Why does this happen?

Comment: have you tried `json_decode($res->getBody(),true)` ,

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately it doesn't remove the <?php tag. :(

Answer (score 0):

try this code, I was using this code to retrieve data from [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net)

```
json_decode((string)$client->get($query_string)->getBody());
```